# Testing HelloSign API embedded signature

Tags: hellosign-api

Hello I am using the HelloSign API, looking to test the embedded signing feature. How am I able to test the embedded document to sign on my test site? I am using the nodejs SDK along with AngularJS. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general walkthrough for embedded signing, which walks you through the server side and client side steps: https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedSigningWalkthrough

Here's an FAQ on testing locally: https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/217048987-What-tools-can-I-use-to-test-the-API-and-callbacks-locally-

For greater detail, please write into apisupport@hellosign.com.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ah thanks @ejadib - I'll keep that in mind in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

-First thing is create an account with Hellosign

- Next thing is creating your API KEY from your registered account.
- Create an API App with your registered hellosign account (This is important because during the setup it will ask for the URL where the Iframe will be created.)
- Now to use it simply include this script (`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.hellosign.com/public/js/hellosign-embedded.LATEST.min.js"></script>`).
- And then finally do this in your client side component file

  ```
  HelloSign.init("CLIENT_ID");
   HelloSign.open({
   url: "SIGN_URL",
   allowCancel: true,
   messageListener: function(eventData) {
       // do something
   }
  });
  ```
- And Voila..!! It will work.